# xslt pass parameters throuh all apply-template calls

Tags: xslt, parameters

In a rather complex xslt file some elements are to be processed twice. This is done by a template with a paramater.

```
    <xsl:template macht="x">
      <xsl:param name="modus"/>

    <!-- comon things to do for both cases -->

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$modus='case1'"> <!-- things to do in case 1 --> </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$modus='case2'"> <!-- things to do in case 2 --> </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
```

The problem is: I cannot simply apply or call this template directly. The element x (for which this template with these two cases is for) is often at a quite low level of the xml input. Almost all ancestor elements have to be processed (in both cases) before it actually comes to x.

The call for the two cases is at the allmost top level.
In html it would be like this

```
<body>
<h1>Case 1</h1>
<xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-parameter name="modus" select="case1"/>

<h1>Case 2</h1>
<xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-parameter name="modus" select="case2"/>
</body>
```

So. How can I make sure, that the parameter reaches the template for x?

Of course, I could replace all

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

calls within the templates for every single ancestor element of x by

```
<xsl:param name="modus">

<!-- What ever content here -->

<xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-parameter name="modus" select="$modus"/></apply-templates>
```

But that would mean a lot of effort. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 has tunnel parameters e.g. with

```
<xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:with-param name="modus" tunnel="yes" select="'foo'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="bar">
  <xsl:param name="modus" tunnel="yes"/>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

you don't have to pass on the parameter explicitly in the templates for ancestors of `bar`. So using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 you can do that.